# Why do grignard reagents add to carbonyls at the carbonyl carbon, and not deprotonate at the alpha carbon to form an enol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, grignard-reagent, nucleophilicity

I thought that since grignards are such strong bases that they would be immediately protonated by the alpha hydrogen since it is an acidic hydrogen. However, I keep seeing answers that are saying that they just add to the carbonyl. I understand that they are strong bases, and therefore make bad leaving groups (forming a stable tetrahedral compound) once they add to the carbonyl, but I don't understand why they would add rather than deprotonate.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134270/grignard-reagent-will-act-as-a-base-or-a-nucleophile https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/113023/grignard-reagent-and-acidic-hydrogen